# preserve image quality

Tags: android, bitmap, gesture

I have a bitmap which is formed from gesture and its comparatively small in appearance.
I want to merge it with an image which has been selected from gallery.
I have done this image blending but the problem is the added gesture image is too small with the gallery image.
I want to merge in such a manner that the small image should be visible enough and should not lose the quality.

Answer (score 1):

Since enlarging the gesture image will lead to pixelation, you may try creating the gesture image with the same size as the image from the gallery. When being edited by the user, scale the gesture image down to fit the screen.

Comment: How to accomplish it! Hlp me out from this!